# how to count the numbers based on two columns

Tags: r

I have a data like this

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, NA, NA, 4L), .Label = c("", "1 x Bruit (U)", "1 x TAMAN (M)", 
"2 x Bruit (U)", "2 x TIKIam(T)"), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("BUX1_T10963", 
"BUX1_T10964", "BUX1_T10965", "BUX1_T10966", "BUX2_T10076"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -28L))
```

I try to make an example so that one can help me better

The first two columns look like this

1 x Bruit (U)   BUX1_T10963
2 x Bruit (U)   BUX1_T10963
2 x Bruit (U)   BUX1_T10963

Here I want to know how many of the BUX1_T10963 has `Bruit (U)`and how many don't have. or has other thing or empty cell

for example in example above, The answer is

BUX1_T10963    has  5 Bruit (U)

The output can look like below

```
                  BUX1_T10963      
Bruit (U)               5
NA                      0
.                       0
.                       0
```

@d.b gave an answer like

```
table(df$V1, df$V2)

                BUX1_T10963 BUX1_T10964 BUX1_T10965 BUX1_T10966 BUX2_T10076
                          0           4           0           0           0
  1 x Bruit (U)           1           1           2           4           0
  1 x TAMAN (M)           0           0           1           0           0
  2 x Bruit (U)           2           4           1           1           1
  2 x TIKIam(T)           0           0           0           3           0
```

But it does not show how many empty assigned to them like the above format and also count the 2 different than 1

```
table(replace(gsub("(\\d x )", "", df$V1), is.na(df$V1), "NA"), df$V2)

            BUX1_T10963 BUX1_T10964 BUX1_T10965 BUX1_T10966 BUX2_T10076
                      0           4           0           0           0
  Bruit (U)           3           5           3           5           1
  NA                  0           0           1           2           0
  TAMAN (M)           0           0           1           0           0
  TIKIam(T)           0           0           0           3           0


BUX1_T10963 should have 4 empty 
BUX1_T10965 should have 1
BUX1_T10966 should have 2
```

Is there a way to make it on the same raw?

Comment: @d.b table does not count the empty spot, make the 2 as a separate one than 1 . Let me show the output above

Comment: Or just `with(df, table(V1, V2, useNA = "ifany"))`, again, the first row with the blank label is the count of blanks.

Comment: @d.b is there a way to make them in the same row ? Please look at above

Comment: So you want the `NA` and blank `""` to be treated the same? Just run `df[df == ""] = NA` first to change all the blanks to `NA`.

Comment: @d.b because the data structure had a problem and it is solved by df[df == ""] <- NA

Comment: @d.b it was a typo. You've put more time into this than me, do you want to write it up?

Comment: @Gregor can with your command ,we also have all counts together? for example 2 x Bruit + 1 x Bruit ? because they are the same

Comment: You just need to add a column to your data where things that you say "are the same" actually have the same values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `table` command does what you want:

```
table(df$V1, df$V2, useNA = "ifany")
```

Table will work on all distinct values. If you want blanks `""` to be equivalent to missing values `NA`, you need to make that change in your data:

```
df[df == ""] = NA
```

Similarly, if the `1 x` or `2 x` doesn't matter, get rid of them. Maybe add a new column

```
df$goodname = gsub(pattern = "^[0-9]+ x ", replacement = "", x = df$V1)

table(df$goodname, df$V2, useNA = "ifany")
            BUX1_T10963 BUX1_T10964 BUX1_T10965 BUX1_T10966 BUX2_T10076
  Bruit (U)           3           5           3           5           1
  TAMAN (M)           0           0           1           0           0
  TIKIam(T)           0           0           0           3           0
  <NA>                0           4           1           2           0
```

---

Pulling out the quantity into its own column and tabulating:

```
library(stringr)
# extract the number
df$quantity = as.numeric(str_extract(df$V1, "^[0-9]+"))
# any missing values assume to be 1
df$quantity[is.na(df$quantity)] = 1

library(reshape2)
dcast(data = df, formula = goodname ~ V2, value.var = "quantity", fun.aggregate = sum, na.rm = T)
#    goodname BUX1_T10963 BUX1_T10964 BUX1_T10965 BUX1_T10966 BUX2_T10076
# 1 Bruit (U)           5           9           4           6           2
# 2 TAMAN (M)           0           0           1           0           0
# 3 TIKIam(T)           0           0           0           6           0
# 4      <NA>           0           4           1           2           0
```

Comment: I think your other question is too broad. This question showed you *how to get from a nice data format to a nice table*, and then showed you *how to get from a slightly bad data format to a nice data format*. Turns out your data is in an even worse data format. Your other question says "How do I take this really bad data format to a nice table?", but what you should be asking is "*How do I turn this really bad data format into a good data format?*", because you already know from this question how to go from nice data to nice table.

Comment: Your other question shouldn't mention the table at all - it is just distracting and makes it confusing. Instead focus on how to break up your compound rows into individual rows with an item name column and a quantity column. And make sure your example data is as general as you need it to be - might there be three items in a row? More? I think if you do that, show sample input and desired output (just the nice data, forget about the table), you will get good quick help. I'm pretty busy this week, so it probably won't be from me.