# how to count several strings assigned to a column?

Tags: r, string, reshape

I recently asked a question which was well answered and I gave the credit to the person who helped me [how to count the numbers based on two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47421811/how-to-count-the-numbers-based-on-two-columns)

```
df2<- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, NA, NA, 5L), .Label = c("1 x Bruit (U)", "1 x Bruit (U) 1 x TAMAN (M)", 
"1 x Bruit (U) 2 x TAMAN (M)", "1 x TAMAN (M) 2 x TAMAN (M)", 
"2 x Bruit (U)", "2 x TIKIam(T)"), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("BUX1_T10963", 
"BUX1_T10964", "BUX1_T10965", "BUX1_T10966", "BUX2_T10076"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -28L))
```

I have another question which I thought I should ask a different question rather than on the same question.

If I have more than one string in the first column, then I cannot get a good results. For example with above question. I get

if I do the following

```
library(stringr)
library(reshape2)
df$goodname = gsub(pattern = "^[0-9]+ x ", replacement = "", x = df$V1)
# extract the number
df$quantity = as.numeric(str_extract(df$V1, "^[0-9]+"))
# any missing values assume to be 1
df$quantity[is.na(df$quantity)] = 1
dcast(data = df, formula = goodname ~ V2, value.var = "quantity", fun.aggregate = sum, na.rm = T)
```

I get the answer like

```
                 goodname BUX1_T10963 BUX1_T10964 BUX1_T10965 BUX1_T10966 BUX2_T10076
1               Bruit (U)           5           9           2           6           2
2 Bruit (U) 1 x TAMAN (M)           0           0           1           0           0
3 Bruit (U) 2 x TAMAN (M)           0           0           1           0           0
4 TAMAN (M) 2 x TAMAN (M)           0           0           1           0           0
5               TIKIam(T)           0           0           0           6           0
6                    <NA>           0           4           1           2           0
```

but I want to have the answer like this

```
                goodname BUX1_T10963 BUX1_T10964 BUX1_T10965 BUX1_T10966 BUX2_T10076
1               Bruit (U)           5           9           4           6       2
2               TAMAN (M)           0           0           6           0       0
3               TIKIam(T)           0           0           0           6       0
4                    <NA>           0           4           1           2       0
5               TTXI1(M)            0           0           0            2       0
```

Comment: How do you get `6` for `BUX1_T10965` in `TAMAN (M)`?

Comment: @discipulus 1 x TAMAN (M) + 2 x TAMAN (M) +TAMAN (M) 2 x TAMAN (M)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution using `dplyr` and `tidyr`. We have different outputs, but since your `df2` does not have any `TTXI1(M)`, I think my output probably makes more sense. The key is to use `separate_rows` to expand rows with multiple records and `separate` to separate the `Times` (`1 x`, `2 x`) and `Label`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df3 <- df2 %>%
  separate_rows(V1, sep = "(?<=\\))\\s(?=[0-9]+)") %>%
  separate(V1, into = c("Times", "Label"), sep = " x ", convert = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(Times = ifelse(is.na(Times), 1, Times)) %>%
  group_by(Label, V2) %>%
  summarise(n = sum(Times)) %>%
  spread(V2, n, fill = 0) %>%
  ungroup()
df3

# # A tibble: 4 x 6
#       Label BUX1_T10963 BUX1_T10964 BUX1_T10965 BUX1_T10966 BUX2_T10076
# *     <chr>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
# 1 Bruit (U)           5           9           4           6           2
# 2 TAMAN (M)           0           0           6           0           0
# 3 TIKIam(T)           0           0           0           6           0
# 4      <NA>           0           4           1           2           0
```

Comment: again I liked and accepted your answer. Would you please explain your code? I want to learn it

Comment: Thanks. Which function would you like to learn more? One way to learn which function does what is to run the code with one more line at a time and compare the output data frame.

Comment: I want to know how you come to a conclusion that you combine these functions? what should I read to get this ability ?

Comment: @nik I encourage you find a tutorial of `dplyr` and `tidyr`. These two packages are very useful.